# Filter out non null objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have list of objects in an array. How can i filter out if any one of key property of the object is null/empty. In given example the first record is perfect and the 2nd and 4th record have missing properties. So my ideal output should be 1st & 2nd.

```js
[{
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "qwe",
        "Lead": "abc",
        "Manager": "xyz"
        "id":"1",
        "Designation":"COO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "dfg",
        "Lead": "",
        "Manager": "lkj"
        "id":"2",
        "Designation":"CTO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "NON-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "out",
        "Lead": "poi",
        "Manager": "",
        "id":"43",
        "Designation":"COO"
    },
    {
        "ServiceArea": "4500-CIO",
        "ManagingDirector": "yhh",
        "Lead": "trr",
        "Manager": "nbb"
        "id":"403",
        "Designation":"CTO"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), then use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check whether every value is truthy.

```js
const arr=[{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"qwe",Lead:"abc",Manager:"xyz",id:"1",Designation:"COO"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"dfg",Lead:"",Manager:"lkj",id:"2",Designation:"CTO"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"out",Lead:"poi",Manager:"",id:"43",Designation:"COO"},{ServiceArea:"4500-CIO",ManagingDirector:"yhh",Lead:"trr",Manager:"nbb",id:"403",Designation:"CTO"}];

const res = arr.filter(e => Object.values(e).every(k => !!k))
console.log(res)
```

If you want to filter by specific keys, you can store the keys in an array and use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all values are truthy.

```js
const arr=[{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"qwe",Lead:"abc",Manager:"xyz",id:"1",Designation:"COO"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"dfg",Lead:"",Manager:"lkj",id:"2",Designation:"CTO"},{ServiceArea:"NON-CIO",ManagingDirector:"out",Lead:"poi",Manager:"",id:"43",Designation:"COO"},{ServiceArea:"4500-CIO",ManagingDirector:"yhh",Lead:"trr",Manager:"nbb",id:"403",Designation:"CTO"}];

const keys = ["Lead"]
const res = arr.filter(e => keys.every(k => !!e[k]))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Any way where i can also specify the keys also? Like only manager and lead is null/empty.

Comment: The [current code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74837154/2) only checks for empty strings, which is not what was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74837145/1) in the question: "_How can i filter out if any one of key property of the object is null/empty_"

Comment: @jsejcksn Good call! I've updated my answer to check for truthiness.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837145/filter-out-non-null-objects-from-array-of-objects/74837154?noredirect=1#comment132073268_74837154) @Spectric [Truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) is also not what was asked in the question: other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (e.g. the integer `0`) are not `null` and also not an empty string. The question asked _specifically_ about those two cases.